# Mule exec Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, mule, esb, procedure

Could someone share how to call a stored procedure under Mule CE, using named parameters?
I would like to use the JDBC component or the new one DB component under AnyPointConnect 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the Procedure calling syntax in Mule 3.6

```css
<db:stored-procedure config-ref="Oracle_Configuration1" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{call apps.create_sales_Order(:p_header_rec_oper,:P_order_number,:P_ordered_date,:P_line_id,:p_flow_Status_code,:P_return_status)}]]></db:parameterized-query>
            <db:in-param name="p_header_rec_oper" value="CREATE"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_order_number" type="INTEGER"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_ordered_date" type="DATE"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_line_id" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <db:out-param name="p_flow_Status_code" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_return_status" type="VARCHAR"/>
            
</db:stored-procedure>

{
• P_return_status: "S",
• P_line_id: "684229",
• p_flow_Status_code: "ENTERED",
• P_ordered_date: "2015-05-22",
• P_order_number: 69393
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call store procedures using the Database element like this

```
<transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="My_Transaction">
        <db:stored-procedure config-ref="My_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[call my_procedure(:p_param1,:p_param2,:p_output)]]></db:parameterized-query>
            <db:in-param name="p_param1" type="VARCHAR" value="#[flowVars.param]"/>
            <db:in-param name="p_param2" type="VARCHAR" value="#['Hardcoded_value']"/>
            <db:out-param name="p_output" type="VARCHAR"/>
        </db:stored-procedure>
    </transactional>
```

In this example I've put the procedure call in an transactional scope.
You also have to declare the db configuration before with the datasource

Comment: Works fine! Just to double check, I asked about named parameters in order to not break the flow in case of any procedure change. Using this approach, the jdbc call the procedure using the namo of the parameter instead of the index, is it correct? Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: yes right it will use the name., but you have to pay attention that the parameters are set in the right order (like in my example), this is a bug of mule studio that should be fixed in one of the next release.